# Anylogic change button label dynamically

Tags: java, text, anylogic

I am trying to change the text of an already created Button. On the document page there is a reference saying that there is a property `setText​(java.lang.Object text)` that sets the button label text. However how do I create the text object? At first I thought I should create a ShapeText and pass it as the text argument, but when I tried to do it it changed the label of the button for the name of the ShapeText object reference.

I used this constructor and assigned to the button:

```
ShapeText new_text = new ShapeText​(true, 190.0, 190.0, 0, black, "My new button label", my_new_font, alignment)

button1.setText(new_text)
```

However the label of the button doesn't change to "My new button label". What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use a String argument for the `setText` method of the button element, so you can use `button1.setText("My new button label")`.

(It is probably defined as an Object in the documentation, because the method also works with integer, boolean, etc. type arguments.)

If you need to change the appearance too during runtime, a possible solution is using a Rounded rectangle (or any other shape) and a Text element on top of it instead of the standard Button. The shapes have 'On click' properties where you can call the desired action. Text doesn't have a built-in method to make it bold, but you have lots of other options for customization this way even if you only write simpler code.

Comment: Thanks! I got so focused on the documentation that I didn't even tested this. However, this solution doesn't allow me to change the text appearance, such as make it bold, or changing the font.

Comment: Edited my answer to also include a solution for this problem